# How to make a continuous graph in 3D under an iterative process?

Tags: graphics3d, iterators

I'm solving a problem in which I have to plot a series of image points $P'$ from a set of points $P$ that lies 5 cm away from a sphere with radius 2 cm, in such a way that all $P'$ lies inside the sphere.

My problem lies that as a beginner in *Mathematica* I don't know how to use the command [`While`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/While.html) in order to make a final graph in 3D with those image points.

---

For the moment I'm testing with this code, but surely there's something wrong:

```
y = 5 
n = 0
While[n < y, Print[n]; n = n + 0.5]
While[n < y, 
Show[Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.1], 
Point[{n, 0, 0}, VertexColors -> {Green}]}]]; n++]
```

Comment: There appear to be multiple issues with your code. (e.g. the second loop is never executed since `n=y` after the first one). Try to look at the documentation and its many examples for the functions you are using, e.g. [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html?q=Graphics3D). Then you can ask specific questions if you still have problems. Also, Mathematica uses a mainly functional programming style, where you normally don't need explicit loops (You can look at other questions on this site, and the documentation page about Functional programming for a start).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour] so you learn the basic rules of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. [Your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), but its a good idea to wait 24hours for other answers before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to program in a style that doesn't come natural in Wolfram Language. Your code in Mathematica style should look like this.

```
Graphics3D[
 {
  PointSize[0.1]
  , Table[
   Point[{n, 0, 0}, VertexColors -> {Green}]
   , {n, 0, 5, 0.5}
   ]
  }
 ]
```

Now if you want to plot many [`Point`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Point.html) outside a [`Sphere`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sphere.html) you can do something like this:

```
Graphics3D[
 {
  Opacity[0.3]
  , Red
  , Sphere[{1, 1, 1}, 2]
  , Green
  , Table[
   Point[RandomReal[{2, 4}, 3]]
   , {n, 1000}
   ]
  }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

<sub>Code and plots on *Mathemathica v 11.1.1*</sub>